# Create a Wordpress post with xmlrpc and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, xml-rpc

I have a dynamic page where the user can fill some fields. Those users will all have an account on a WordPress blog. I would like to allow them to directly post the content generated by the webpage to the blog. I don't want to store their password in the server so I want to do this client-side with JQuery.

I have looked both at the standard [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method and the [rpc plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/rpc) but I didn't manage to make them work. For example, my latest attempts were something like this:

```
wprpc = $.rpc('http://blog.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php', 'xml', callback);
function callback(server) {
    answer = server.newPost(0,'user','pass','<struct><title>TestRPC</title></struct>');
    alert(answer);
}
```

and a desperate one:

```
$.post('http://blogurl.com/xmlrpc.php', { blogid: 0, username: "user", password: "pass", struct: "<struct><title>Test</title></struct>" }, function(data) {alert(data);}, 'xml');
```

but it silently failed (the callback is not even called).

How would you do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the origin policy will trip you up as Doug pointed out, you could have a  script on one server post the results to the other, a sort of proxy. It's a bit of a hack, but it'd work. I'd personally use PHP and cURL to do it.

Comment: The thing is it would require this server to see the users passwords (which are part of the xmlrpc request), and I would rather avoid that... Thanks to both of you for pointing me to the Same Origin issue, I guess I'll have to drop that feature and let users copy/paste for now. Later I could probably write my own extension.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make a cross domain `POST` request using jQuery or any other JavaScript technology. This is because of the [`same origin`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) policy required for security reasons. The only way you will be able to accomplish this is via a server proxy on the same domain, subdomain, protocol and port as the jQuery code.

Not sure what server technology you are using, but you could look into [Simple PHP Proxy](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/) by Ben Alman.

Comment: Oh, this is too bad... But then, how does work the firefox extensions which allows to post to your blog (like http://deepestsender.mozdev.org/) for example? I can't touch the WordPress server (it should work with standard wordpress.com blogs). Can you see any other way of solving my problem?

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment. I thought the single origin thing was on the server side but it seems to be in the browser side. I guess my only solution would be to write my own extension. Could be fun :).